# OPENROWSET duplicate columns from stored procedure issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, openrowset

I am using OPENROWSET on a stored procedure (since the stored procedure returns an unknown number of columns).  OPENROWSET does not allow for duplicate columns.  My issue is that the stored procedure joins a crazy number of tables dynamically and hence creates a bunch of duplicate keys.  Any ideas as to how to get around this problem?  Thank you very much.

Comment: `EXEC WITH RESULTSET`

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012+ allows to use [`EXEC WITH RESULTSETS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

```
EXEC uspGetEmployeeManagers 16
WITH RESULT SETS
( 
   ([Reporting Level] int NOT NULL,
    [ID of Employee] int NOT NULL,
    [Employee First Name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Employee Last Name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Employee ID of Manager] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    [Manager First Name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Manager Last Name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL )
);
```

You can alias name which collides.

Comment: thanks but using sql server 2008.  anyhow i'm joining 50+ tables and would rather not deal with identifying individual columns.  even when i joined the 50+ tables i wrote a loop to dynamically build my query string to then execute.  i guess within that loop, i can loop through individual columns and skip over the columns i don't want but that would be quite intensive.  hoping there is a better way out there.

Comment: Can't you in dynamic code just aliases names with suffix `_1, _2` ...?

Comment: that would work but i would still have to loop through all the columns for each table?